# How to join table with dynamic identifier in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a table name `table` containing two columns `foreign_table_name`, and `foreign_key`.

Is it possible to write a `SELECT` query that would `JOIN` values of this table and  the table which name is specified in the column `foreign_table_name` ?

For instance, if we know that all possible targetted foreign tables have a `name` field, I would like to know if I could write something that would:

```
SELECT table.foo, table.bar, foreign_table.name 
FROM table
  JOIN $foreign_table AS foreign_table 
       ON (foreign_table.id = table.foreign_key
           $foreign_table = table.foreign_table);
```

Any solution using PlpgSQL is of course accepted.

Here's a simple content:

```
Table ``table``
------------------------------------------------
| foo | bar | foreign_table_name | foreign_key |
------------------------------------------------
|  A  |  1  | fruits             | 8           |
|  B  |  2  | vegetable          | 5           |
------------------------------------------------

Table ``fruit``
---------------
| id  | name  |
---------------
| 8   | apple |
---------------

Table ``vegetable``
----------------
| id  | name   |
----------------
| 5   | carrot |
----------------
```

The expected result table would be:

```
----------------------
| foo | bar | name   |
----------------------
|  A  |  1  | apple  |
|  B  |  2  | carrot |
----------------------
```

EDIT: I added the full table example in an attempt to be clearer.

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL/a prepared statement to do this.  In a basic SQL query, you have to have an explicit table.

Comment: Look into the `EXECUTE` command in PL/PgSQL. Or generate the query from your client.

Comment: @CraigRinger I already looked at ``EXECUTE`` statement, but even with this I didn't manage to get a solution. So if you have something in mind, please share it.

Answer (score 9):

It's usually way easier to do this sort of thing on the client side, but if you want it's possible with PL/PgSQL, e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dynamic_call(tblname text)
RETURNS TABLE (foo int, bar text, fname text)
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('
    SELECT t.foo, table.bar, f."name"
    FROM mytable t
    JOIN %I AS f ON (f.id = t.foreign_key);', tblname);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

For more information, see the PL/PgSQL documentation.

Comment: I was probably not clear enough in stating my question. So I edited to add a practical example. Your answer do not help me because: 1 - it's a function, I asked for a table, 2- the table name has to come from the base table column ``foreign_table_name``. However, I learned some plpgsql while reading your proposition, especially the ``RETURNS TABLE`` that I was missing. With that, I'll probably manage to find a solution. Thx.

Comment: @vaab You cannot do this without dynamic SQL, and therefore must use either a PL/PgSQL function, or client-side generated SQL.