# Join on dynamic column name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need join two tables only with column names and values.

```
article
-------
id | cf_camera | cf_display | cf_...
1  | 15        | NULL       | NULL

custom_field
------------
id | column_name  | name | description
1  | 'cf_camera'  |      |
2  | 'cf_display' |      |
```

I tried to write query but don't know how to make dynamic column joining with article table.

```
select 
  a.id, 
  cf.id 
from 
  custom_field cf
inner join
  article a 
on 
  a.cf.column_name is not null and 
  a.cf.column_name::integer > 0
```

Problem is here `a.cf.column_name`.

Comment: You should use "RETURN QUERY EXECUTE" as [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21619189/how-to-join-table-with-dynamic-identifier-in-postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use variables for schema elements like table and columns names in sql, but you can build a query (as text) in a plpgsql function and execute it using the EXECUTE statement (as pointed out by @user3222580)

This is a example I build the query and return the result as TABLE. You have to define the structure of the data you want to return in the RETURNS part.

I tried to reproduce your test case but I am not sure that the function really do, want you need. Take it as code sample. I iterate over the records in the table 'articles' and take the value of the column 'column_name' for building a SELECT ... UNION SELECT query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function() RETURNS TABLE (a_id int, cf_id int) as
  $$
  DECLARE _column_name text; _query text; counter int;
  BEGIN
    _query = '';
    counter = 0;

    FOR _column_name in SELECT column_name  FROM custom_field LOOP

      IF counter > 0 THEN
        _query = _query || ' UNION ';
      END IF;
      _query = _query ||'select 
      a.id, 
      cf.id 
    from 
      custom_field cf
    inner join
      article a 
    on 
      '||_column_name||' is not null and 
      '||_column_name||'::integer > 0';

      counter = counter+ 1;
    END LOOP;
    raise info '%', _query;
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE _query;
  END;
  $$
language plpgsql;
```

So can you call the function:

```
SELECT * from test_function();
```